# Conversation List System

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i am actually building a conversation system and i have a page that displays all of the User's conversations, and allows him to select which one he wants to reply to, the general design is as follows:

I uploaded an image of the general structure here:

http://tinypic.com/r/2myvhno/8

So its like conversation lists one column, and the conversation itself takes the right column. When the user clicks on the conversation, then the correct conversation on the right hand side will pop out, so i think this will need some ajax to not refresh the page while sending the php code over to query the database for the conversation based on the id.

So the general functionality works like this:

1. User selects conversation, conversation displays on right.
2. User selects another conversation, conversation on the right changes.

I am fine with the php and querying database to get the conversation but not familiar with the ajax/javascript and html needed to allow users to select conversations, and for the correct conversation to display.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried anything already? Is there a problem

Comment: I am thinking about where to start, the most important part I'm unsure is how do you change the conversation on the right when the user clicks on another button on the left

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are getting the conversation by a "#user_id". and do as follows

You need something like this,
1) give an id to right, say "#right"

2) after including necessary jquery library, get the click event of particular user

```
$(document).on("click", "#user_id", function(){
    var user_id = $(this).attr('id_of_particular_user'); //you are getting the user id here
     var request = $.ajax({
                        url: "your_path_to_a_php_file_that_gives_you_the_conversation.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: { user_id: user_id },
                        beforeSend: function(){
                            self.html("loading please wait...");
                        }
                    });

    //WHEN SUCCESS
    request.success(function( data ) {
        $("#right").html(data); //this line will replace the right with echoed content from php file
    });
});
```

3. your_path_to_a_php_file_that_gives_you_the_conversation.php here echo the conversation as html code, like `echo "<li>conversation line</li>";`

Comment: Hi Arun, thanks for your answer, this makes sense to me, firstly, i will need to know which conversation user clicks, so i will name the conversation list div on the left as user_id, so when the jQuery detects the click on the div, it will check for the specific user_id allocated to the div with id user_id, as different users have different number of conversations with different people. So then after it gets the user-id VALUE, it sends it to the php file for processing, comes back with data and appends the html on the right side, am i right to say that?

Comment: Hey Arun, was doing the code, my php file echoes the results back to the ajax, but my conversation on the right side has a couple of divs with styling needed to make it look nice, how do i incorporate it with the ajax, especially with the last few lines: request.success(function( data ) {
        $("#right").html(data); //this line will replace the right with echoed content from php file
    });

Comment: Oh, i think i understand, i would need to echo out the html on the php side as well, so that they will completely swap sides, i will try that out and see if it works.

Comment: Hey Arun, its giving me the error: SyntaxError: Function statements must have a name.

Comment: hi Arun, thanks this issue is resolved, i posted a new question, you may want to take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27343260/chat-list-ajax-functionality?noredirect=1#comment43144311_27343260